# Add Auto-Increment ID to existing table?

Tags: mysql, sql, definition, auto-increment

I have a pre-existing table, containing 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'password' and 'ip'. But now I want an auto-increment column. However, when I enter:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I get the following:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Any advice?:)

Comment: can you post your existing table definition?

Comment: please post output of `describe users`

Comment: tried that, but it just returns the table. what do you need?

Comment: @CharlesJenkins Could you pick the correct answer?

Comment: MODIFY can also be used  as :   ALTER TABLE users
MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;  /* AUG Dated 2019*/

Answer (score 151):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

for an existing primary key

Comment: #1068 - Multiple primary key defined

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, replacing 'AUTO_INCREMENT' with 'IDENTITY(1,1)' worked for me.

Comment: Note that this adds an ID-column as the last column in the table. Add `FIRST` to the query to make it the first in this table.

Comment: @CharlesJenkins To avoid the "Multiple primary key" error, drop the existing primary key before defining the new one: `ALTER TABLE users DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: To make it the first column, use `FIRST` e.g `ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST`

Comment: Got errors with that sintax this worked for me
   ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

Answer (score 115):

If you don't care whether the auto-id is used as `PRIMARY KEY`, you can just do

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

I just did this and it worked a treat.

Comment: This worked for me and set the auto_increment id column as the primary key.

Comment: What does the `FIRST` do there?

Comment: @Cees Timmerman: The keyword FIRST indicates that the new column will be the first column in the table. Alternatively, you can specify a particular position using AFTER existent_col_name. If neither FIRST nor AFTER are used then the new column is added after all current columns.

Comment: what if I want to create an index on id but not a PK?

Comment: @morpheus this adds a UNIQUE index which is an index in itself. I don't like having a column called id which isn't a PK though.

Comment: UNIQUE did the trick for me. Struggled for a while altering an table with existing primary keys but needed auto_increment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 47):

If you want to add AUTO_INCREMENT in an existing table, need to run following SQL command:

```
 ALTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key
```

Comment: that didn't work! Got this error:
#1068 - Multiple primary key defined

Comment: you get `Multiple primary key defined` because you already have a primary key on the table. A table can only have one primary key. Retry the above command on the table when it doesn't have a primary key

Comment: To avoid the "Multiple primary key" error, drop the existing primary key before defining the new one: `ALTER TABLE users DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 28):

First you have to remove the primary key of the table

```
ALTER TABLE nametable DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

and now yo can add the autoincrement ...

```
ALTER TABLE nametable ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: cannot drop, then ADD id. Will get `Duplicate column name 'id'`

Comment: @JohnJoe, that's because you already have the id column. Try this: ALTER TABLE nametable DROP PRIMARY KEY, MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 20):

Well, you must first drop the `auto_increment` and `primary key` you have and then add yours, as follows:

```
-- drop auto_increment capability
alter table `users` modify column id INT NOT NULL;
-- in one line, drop primary key and rebuild one
alter table `users` drop primary key, add primary key(id);
-- re add the auto_increment capability, last value is remembered
alter table `users` modify column id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: got this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY(id)' at line 1

Comment: look your code u posted it miss LTER and not ALter , make sure u copied it all

Comment: thanks, but now i've got this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY(id)' at line 3

sorry!

Comment: got this:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id)' at line 1

Comment: well you can follow those steps in my answer

Comment: You had 3 typos in this answer (modify not change, "id id" and comments need a space after them). I have edited the answer to fix them.

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE domains modify COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.27 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
mysql> desc domains;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| domain | varchar(128) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Answer (score 18):

If you run the following command :

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

This will show you the error :

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'id'
```

This is because this command will try to add the new column named `id` to the existing table.

To modify the existing column you have to use the following command :

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

This should work for changing the existing column constraint....!

Answer (score 11):

Delete the primary key of a table if it exists:

```
 ALTER TABLE `tableName` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Adding an auto-increment column to a table :

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD `Column_name` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Modify the column which we want to consider as the primary key:

```
alter table `tableName` modify column `Column_name` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Answer (score 7):

Drop the primary index from the table:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` DROP INDEX `PRIMARY`;
```

Then add the id column (without a primary index). I have used a big int because I am going to have lots of data but INT(11) should work just as well:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD COLUMN `id` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL FIRST;
```

Then modify the column with auto-increment (thanks php). It needs to be a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName ` MODIFY COLUMN `id` BIGINT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I have just tried this on a table of mine and it appears to have worked.

Comment: It's also possible to perform the last 2 steps in a single query, though:

```ALTER TABLE PremiumPackages ADD COLUMN id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;```

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 6):

Just change the ADD to MODIFY and it will works !

Replace

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

To

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE id int( 30 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

the integer parameter is based on my default sql setting
have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key FIRST
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an id with a primary key and identity:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST , ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL you have to use SERIAL instead of auto_increment.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

This SQL request works for me :

```
ALTER TABLE users
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT unique
```

Try this. No need to drop your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE `yourDbName`.`YourTableName`
CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC) VISIBLE;
;

Answer (score -1):

Check for already existing primary key with different column. If yes, drop the primary key using:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_Col1
GO
```

and then write your query as it is.

Answer (score -2):

Proceed like that :

```
Make a dump of your database first

Remove the primary key like that
```

ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP PRIMARY KEY

```
Add the new column like that
```

ALTER TABLE yourtable add column Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD primary KEY Id(Id)

The table will be looked and the AutoInc updated.