# How to insert auto_increment in an already created table in liquibase

Tags: sql, jpa, liquibase

How to insert auto_increment in an already created table in liquibase?

User table already exists.

```
<createTable tableName="user">
   <column name="user" type="varchar(255)">
      <constraint nullable="false">
   </column>
   <column name="user_id" type="varchar(255)"/>
   <column name="password" type="varchar(255)"/>
   <column name="email" type="varchar(255)"/>
</createTable>
<addPrimaryKey tableName="user"> columnNames="user" constraintName="user_pk">
```

Duplicate user occurred in userTable.
The pk was removed because the user could have a duplicate name.

However, since we need to have the value of @Id, if we add the ID and set the autoIncrement, there will be a problem.

```
<dropPrimaryKey tableName="user"/>
<addColumn tableName="user">
    <column name="id" type="BIGINT"/>
</addColumn>
<createSequence
    incrementBy="1" 
    maxValue="9223372036854775807" 
    minValue="1"  
    startValue="1"
    sequenceName="user_sequence"/>
```

**Error Message**

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "id" of relation "user" contains null values [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE "public"."user" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_user" PRIMARY KEY ("id")]

Comment: Seems like you have null values already in your ID column, which is not allowed for primary key columns. You have to fix those first.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443043/cannot-add-a-non-primary-key-identity-column).

```
<changeSet id="1" author="Me">
    <dropPrimaryKey tableName="tv_campaigns"/>
    <addColumn tableName="tv_campaigns">
        <column name="ID" type="bigint(20)" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" unique="true"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
    <addAutoIncrement tableName="tv_campaigns" columnName="ID" columnDataType="bigint(20)"/>
</changeSet>
```

Try using the `addAutoIncrement` tag, read more about it [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/add-auto-increment.html).