# Remove redundant records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I've a table without PK and auto increment columns, I have same rows at mulitple times inserts. I wanna keep only one row and to remove other rows.

I have found more than 2000 rows matching the redundancy, how can I eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: How did you find duplicates?

Comment: See this [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839651/mysql-delete-rows-where-dates-are-not-the-newest) asked minutes ago

Comment: Share sample data..

Answer (score -2):

Add an auto-incrementing ID to your table:

[Add Auto-Increment ID to existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753321/add-auto-increment-id-to-existing-table)

Then find your duplicates and delete them by their IDs.

Comment: This got voted down because someone thinks this is not an acceptable way to remove duplicates or because the question was poor and I shouldn't have answered it?